電車(で/に)傘を忘れてしまいました
According to my textbook, and some googling we need to use に here. Other threads on this site have some good explanations regarding the differences between に vs で (as in 部屋で泣いている, vs ni)
https://hinative.com/questions/19223447
In this thread the user suggests that if we use で then it would imply that the actual existence of the umbrella disappeared while we were on the train (if im understanding the japanese correctly)
They mention another example
「運動場でボールを投げる」 - A person in the playground is throwing a ball to something/someone else within the playground
「運動場にボールを投げる」 - The ball is being thrown from outside the playground…?
So whats the deal…? Im still unclear on why we cant use で here, and a bit confused.

I offered a response, but it may be best if a native on this site answer this question.

Just to clarify, the Japanese HiNative answer didn't say that the umbrella actually disappeared, but that it disappeared from their head, i.e., they forgot about the existence of umbrella while on the train, rather than accidentally leaving it there.

Judging by your username... Do you speak Chinese by any chance? Please ignore me if you don't. If you do, then the language logic behind this is actually the same in Chinese. 我把伞忘到电车上了, the word 到(usually used to denote direction of action) is also used here. If you use で, that implies an unchanging location, whose equivalent Chinese would be 在电车上，我把伞忘了. Doesn't make much sense now.

に is a "target location" or destination particle you use when you place something somewhere, and this includes leaving or forgetting something somewhere. The same type of に is used in the following sentences:

紙に漢字を書いた
壁に落書きを残した
実家にアルバムを置いてきた
家に宿題を忘れてきた

When you forget something, it means you have placed it somewhere rather than having kept it on your person, so I think the use of the target particle is understandable.
On the other hand, 電車で傘を忘れる sounds puzzling. It would only make sense if you are deliberately trying to erase the concept of umbrella from your memory while you're on a train.

Your examples make sense to me, but how is using で in this example fundamentally different then doing action X at location Y? For example 駅で新聞を買いました... Namely [location] で [action at particular location] => [forget] で [on the train]..?

@BingChilling Ultimately, you have to just memorize how to say this. Logically speaking, I agree that 電車で傘を忘れた should equally make sense, but people don't say this for whatever reason.

OK fair enough. I was just curious if there was a more grammatical reason. I agree languages aren't bounded to logic / rules

I think a point is when learners hear “target location” they assume volition (and thus intent) is involved automatically. This is practically the case with verbs like 残す, but I guess the point is just the fact that the object goes to the target location rather than volition being emphasized during the action.

@BingChilling Usually, people mention 忘れる when they notice they've left an item behind somewhere, so they focus on the last location. If the topic is about when or where it happens rather than the result, 電車で傘を忘れる would be probably heard.

TLDR; 忘れる has two meanings that English treats the same: losing a memory, and leaving something somewhere. In Japanese, the former uses で as forgetting a memory is treated as an action, while the latter uses に as some item exists somewhere.

に does not imply an action at a location, while で implies an action at a location, so 運動場にボールを投げる is to throw a ball into the playground as に indicates it cannot be an action that occurs within the playground itself, but rather a location target.
For your example, 電車(に/で)傘を忘れてしまいました, you "technically" did not perform the action of forgetting your umbrella (it is more something that occurred than something that was performed), if you dropped your umbrella, then that is an action, and thus you would say 電車で傘を落としてしまいました.

EDIT: OP makes a good point that my explanation may not be the best, since it does not clarify how "intent" works. I realize this is because English has two uses of "to forget." Here is this explanation:

忘れる has one sense that means something was left somewhere; so although we can focus on the fact that forgetting itself is an action, to say you left something somewhere means it still exists in that place.

HOWEVER, check this one:

忘れる also has the sense of actually failing to recall something. You forgot the lyrics at the concert. You did not physically leave the lyrics at the concert, so this is the action of forgetting itself.

Japanese makes a distinction between forgetting because you left something somewhere, versus forgetting because you lost the memory.
I hope this clarifies things.

Just to make this more clear, lets flip things.

コンサートで歌詞を忘れた; if this was not you could not recall the lyrics, it would instead be you left, perhaps, lyric sheets at the concert.


電車で財布を忘れてしまいました; this is like if you failed to recall the concept of the wallet on the train. More clearly, change 財布 into 計画, so that you say "you forgot the plan on the train"; now you have an image of some heist mission that may go wrong.


LAST EDIT. Let us go through Naruto's examples with this logic.

紙に漢字を書いた; Not the action at a location, but an action that went to something; this is your 運動場にボールを投げる example, where here, kanji was written on the paper.


壁に落書きを残した; Not the action of hanging the scroll, but that the scroll exists on the wall, so に


実家にアルバムを置いてきた; The album exists at the parent's house; here, 置く does not carry action, but implies the location of something.


家に宿題を忘れてきた; And finally, the homework still exists at the house.

If you have further questions please comment.

Mabye semantics, but how is not forgetting something in X location not performing an action...? Are you referring to the physical tangible action of dropping something, implying で should only be used with verbs that are physical actions? (Forgetting something is not a physical verb but Dropping or touching something is...?)

That you forgot the umbrella was something that happened; you as the agent did not deliberately do the action of forgetting the umbrella.

So are you suggesting that the intent of your action has an indication whether to use に or で? Forgetting something is un-intentional so you use に？

Check my edit; does this make sense?
